# How to assign non unique incrementing index (index markup) in Spark SQL, set back to 0 on joining the specific value from another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

There is a DataFrame of `data` like

```
|timestamp          |value|
|2021-01-01 12:00:00| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:01| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:02| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:03| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:04| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:05| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:06| 10.0|
|2021-01-01 12:00:07| 10.0|
```

and DataFrame of `events` like

```
|timestamp          |event|
|2021-01-01 12:00:01| true|
|2021-01-01 12:00:05| true|
```

based on that I'd like to add one more column to the initial DataFrame that is an `index` of the data since beginning of the `event`:

```
|timestamp          |value|index|
|2021-01-01 12:00:00| 10.0|    1|
|2021-01-01 12:00:01| 10.0|    2|
|2021-01-01 12:00:02| 10.0|    3|
|2021-01-01 12:00:03| 10.0|    4|
|2021-01-01 12:00:04| 10.0|    5|
|2021-01-01 12:00:05| 10.0|    1|
|2021-01-01 12:00:06| 10.0|    2|
|2021-01-01 12:00:07| 10.0|    3|
```

I have tried with

```
.withColumn("index",monotonically_increasing_id())
```

but there is no way to set it back to 0 at joining it with some other DataFrame. So, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `data` df with `event` df on `timestamp` then use a conditional cumulative sum on `event` column to define groups. Finally, partition by the `group` column to set row number.

Something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val result = data.join(
    events, 
    Seq("timestamp"), 
    "left"
).withColumn(
    "group",
    sum(when(col("event"), 1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.orderBy("timestamp"))
).withColumn(
    "index",
    row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("timestamp"))
).drop("group", "event")

result.show
//+-------------------+-----+-----+
//|          timestamp|value|index|
//+-------------------+-----+-----+
//|2021-01-01 12:00:00| 10.0|    1|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:01| 10.0|    1|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:02| 10.0|    2|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:03| 10.0|    3|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:04| 10.0|    4|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:05| 10.0|    1|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:06| 10.0|    2|
//|2021-01-01 12:00:07| 10.0|    3|
//+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Window function to achieve it:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSessionRow, Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Example data after joining the original DFs (I changed the `timestamp` column to integer type for simplicity):

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(timestamp=0, value='foo', event=True),
    Row(timestamp=1, value='foo', event=None),
    Row(timestamp=2, value='foo', event=None),
    Row(timestamp=3, value='foo', event=None),
    Row(timestamp=4, value='foo', event=None),
    Row(timestamp=5, value='foo', event=True),
    Row(timestamp=6, value='foo', event=None),
    Row(timestamp=7, value='foo', event=None),
])
```

Then I create a column with a `group_id` by forward-filling the first timestamp for the "groups".
This `group_id` can then be used to create the index using `F.row_number()`:

```py
(
    df
    .withColumn('group_id', F.when(F.col('event'), F.col('timestamp')))
    .withColumn('group_id', F.last('group_id', ignorenulls=True).over(Window.orderBy('timestamp')))
    .withColumn('index', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('group_id').orderBy('timestamp')))
    .show()
)

# Output:
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----+
|timestamp|value|event|group_id|index|
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----+
|        0|  foo| true|       0|    1|
|        1|  foo| null|       0|    2|
|        2|  foo| null|       0|    3|
|        3|  foo| null|       0|    4|
|        4|  foo| null|       0|    5|
|        5|  foo| true|       5|    1|
|        6|  foo| null|       5|    2|
|        7|  foo| null|       5|    3|
+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----+
```